# how to extract the values between parentheses and plot them at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, text-files, data-analysis

```
import re
text_file = open('results.txt','r')
string in the "file_lines" list
file_lines = text_file.readlines()
list_extracted_data = []
for line in file_lines:
flag = re.search('\AId of the track: 1,',line)
if flag:
    searched_phrase = re.search(r'\B\(.*',line)
    start_index, end_index = searched_phrase.start(), searched_phrase.end()
    list_extracted_data.append(line[start_index:end_index])
    print(list_extracted_data)

import pandas as pd
final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','X','Y'])
for K, pair in enumerate(list_extracted_data):
this_X = float(pair.split(',')[0][1:])
this_Y = float(pair.split(',')[1][:-1])
final_df = final_df.append({'id':K,'X':this_X,'Y':this_Y},ignore_index=True)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from google.colab import files

a = "Y"
b = "id"
y = final_df[a]
X = final_df.drop([a,b], axis=1)
plt.plot(X, y, color = 'k', linewidth = 3)

ax = plt.gca()
ax.axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.axes.yaxis.set_visible(False)

plt.savefig("1.png")
files.download("1.png")
```

This is the code i used to extract the values betweeen parantheses from lines based on the number of the track then used the values to plot a graph and save the image. i want to extract all values between parentheses in the file and build graphs as images then save them at the same time instead of changing the id of track every time because the file has many track IDs.

the lines in the file look like this:

```
- Id of the track: 1, Last ping index in which track has been seen: 94, Center of Mass of the contour: (0.8835006455995176, -0.07697617837544447)
- Id of the track: 1, Last ping index in which track has been seen: 188, Center of Mass of the contour: (0.7836836384728582, -0.535822562170735)
- Id of the track: 1, Last ping index in which track has been seen: 167, Center of Mass of the contour: (0.7115418821577216, -0.30609913665151306)
- Id of the track: 2, Last ping index in which track has been seen: 181, Center of Mass of the contour: (0.8135222802894966, -0.8494988889677038)
- Id of the track: 2, Last ping index in which track has been seen: 181, Center of Mass of the contour: (0.8135222802894966, -0.8494988889677038)
- Id of the track: 2, Last ping index in which track has been seen: 216, Center of Mass of the contour: (0.8629851729535374, -0.8695683157282984)
- Id of the track: 3, Last ping index in which track has been seen: 227, Center of Mass of the contour: (1.2604523543671307, 0.8563692555868321)
- Id of the track: 3, Last ping index in which track has been seen: 236, Center of Mass of the contour: (1.2438380252551318, 0.8616537883641505)
```

Comment: You could use the string `index()` method to find where the parentheses are located.

Comment: I already know where the parentheses are located, i just need to get all the values between them at the same time instead of changing the track id every time to plot the graph because the file is huge.

Comment: If you have the indexes of the parentheses, then you can use a slice to get the characters in between them.